# Evidences for VMWare Snapshot restoration from Guest OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esx, snapshot

I have few VMWare servers managed by an external company and I suspect a snapshot restoration happened on one of my server (MS Windows 2008 Server).

I suspected this because there was a windows update on 16th of October and I deployed a specific version of my software the 10th. 
On 30th of October the software was still in the previous version.

As I am not 100% sure that is an issue with VMWare (it could be my deploy job that fail that day) before opening a request on their side, I would like to know if there is any evidence I can find on the Guest OS 
(Windows 2008 Server), in files or in the event log or somewhere else, that a snapshot restoration has been done.

Note also I do not have access to the VMWare software but only to the Guest OS and the restoration could be done by another way then VMWare snapshot restoration (like some backups software).

Comment: The most obvious clue would be that the OS was restarted.

Comment: Another clue would be a timelapse in the eventviewer